# How to number repeated values in a column in R?

Tags: r

I have a big dataset where some names are repeated, like below.

| Name | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AH | 2013 | 1800 |
| AH | 2014 | 2400 |
| AH | 2015 | 2300 |
| BC | 2013 | 1900 |
| BC | 2014 | 1600 |
| KP | 2013 | 3600 |
| DN | 2013 | 2800 |

I'd like to know how to create a column for numbering repeated names sequentially.

| Name | Year | Value | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AH | 2013 | 1800 | 1 |
| AH | 2014 | 2400 | 2 |
| AH | 2015 | 2300 | 3 |
| BC | 2013 | 1900 | 1 |
| BC | 2014 | 1600 | 2 |
| KP | 2013 | 3600 | 1 |
| DN | 2013 | 2800 | 1 |

I found a previous ask with the following code

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

weighted_df %>% 
   mutate(Number = rowid(Name))
```

but I keep getting "Error in is.data.frame(.data) : object 'weighted_df' not found. I'm quite new to R so I'm unsure of what else I can try out, or if I'm using the wrong libraries for the function.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks y'all!

Comment: I believe the libraries and code are ok - and your error suggests that the data.frame called `weighted_df` is not found in your environment. Are you sure your data object is called `weighted_df`?

Comment: I was so certain I had it right, but indeed there was a typo. I guess that was a super simple solution, but thank you so much for responding!!